# How to sort an NSMutableArray List of objects in alphabetical order

Tags: objective-c, sorting

I have an object with different values that is name,nameid, lifebeging,lifeEndiging .... etc,

```
for loop
{
    // here i will get name, ids, other value for each object
    Search *Obj=[artistslist objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

```
0 obj.name=  //string values1 get from parser
1 obj.name=   //string values1
2 obj.name=  //string values1
3 obj.name=  //string values1
4 obj.name=  //string values1
```

I am getting values in the artistList then i need to sort only by  name  not other feilds

when i use this below statement

```
[artistsList sortUsingSelector:@selector(NSOrderedAscending:)];
```

i am getting exception here ,it is not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSOrderedAscending` is not a selector, it's an enumeration constant and is one of the three possible return values the selector you *do* specify should return.  For NSStrings, [`caseInsensitiveCompare:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-caseInsensitiveCompare_) is a good one, or as jrtc27 suggests `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` if you are sorting to present to the user.  If not a string, you can define your own method that compares two objects and returns `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedDescending` or `NSOrderedSame`.

Answer (score 2):

isn't the correct selector to use `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`?

Answer (score -3):

From where you store the data in artistlist?

If you store it from Database then u can use ORDER BY query to sort...